# Eclipse with cdt not running on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-cdt

I installed eclipse with cdt (C/C++) on my ubuntu 18.04. But when I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

[image: Error message]

Here is what it says:

```
!SESSION Mon Jan 13 18:33:35 KST 2020 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2020-01-13 18:33:35.945
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I tried to google it but could not find any good reference. If anyone has experience, I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: The version (3.8) of Eclipse you are using is very old (8 years and 12 releases old)  and won't work with the version of Java you are using. Move to a newer version of Eclipse 2019-12 (4.14) is  the current version.

Comment: @greg-449 Thanks for the comment! I did as you said, and before installation begins I removed the old one, and after installing the newest one I can run it using the terminal but when I try to run it using the icon on app menu it still gives me the same error. What might be the problem here?

Comment: I don't use Linux so I can't say. Possibly ask on https://askubuntu.com/